# A faster way to be notified of answers to a question

Tags: discussion, answers, email-notification

I'm slowly becoming addicted to StackExchange, and was wondering if there was a way that I can be emailed answers to my questions quicker or instantly? I checked the the 'Settings,' and the earliest option is 'daily.'

I would like to echo some other users that have posted similar questions/requests; I come to StackExchange for help as a last resort —aka after I've exhausted my own knowledge/patience and found no help via Google. If it has come to that, that means I kind of really need to get this answer and as soon as possible. On top of that I know the the idea is to spend time on the site doing a 'give-and-take,' but when I'm at work, that's not an option.

Thus, I was wondering if a feature that a feature similar to 'instant' or say within x amount of minutes will ever be in the works?

Comment: refresh... refresh... refresh... :)

Comment: Shoot, I used to have a funny phrase for just sitting in front of computer and refreshing constantly.

Comment: @Mysticial I use jQuery :)

Comment: There are a bunch of userscripts and add-ons that can do all sorts of things - have you searched [stackapps.com](http://stackapps.com)? For example, I use [Stack Exchange Notifier](http://stackapps.com/questions/3081/senotifier-a-stack-exchange-inbox-notifier-for-mac-os-x).

Comment: I will take a look at this Aaron, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The fastest way to do this is probably going to be just leaving a browser window open to any SE page as long as you're logged in. When you get an answer to one of your questions, it generates a notification.

When these notifications are generated, they instantly (or as close as possible, within a second or two) increment the little red bubble in the top-left corner of the page. When you don't have any unread notifications, the bubble won't be there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Undo, but it does not address my request (of getting quick **email** notifications). I'm am aware of the notifier in the upper left.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you're not going to be able to get quick email notifs from SE.