# When I edit an answer, is the question OP notified about that?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, notifications

I just want to know, until now, every time I edit an answer (of my own) I go and notify the OP by posting a comment something like: *hey look, I edited my answer, why don't you take a look now and see if you like it?* or  just *answer edited*.

So I'm wondering: When I edit an answer, is the OP of the question notified about that?

Comment: The OP gets a notification: `post edited`

Comment: @devnull No, not always.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it depends what "OP" you mean. OP of the question I didn't think got notified. But OP of the answer I thought was always notified. Is that wrong?

Comment: I mean the OP of the Question.

Comment: I might be wrong but I didn't think the OP was notified. However, you shouldn't be making substantial changes to other answers anyhow. If you are changing something such as adding a link to docs then you might comment as you would with your own answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As implemented from [notify-us-when-one-of-our-posts-is-edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2305/notify-us-when-one-of-our-posts-is-edited) the author of a post is notified when **their** post is edited. However the OP of the question is only [notified when the answer is first posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200350/220332), subsequent edits to answers do not trigger notifications; this means you should try to make your answers as good as possible to start with and if you do make substantial additions to it later it may be worth manually notifying the question OP.

There is however a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64692/notify-question-op-and-those-who-marked-it-a-favourite-if-an-answer-has-been-m) requesting that answer edits trigger notifications for question OPs

Comment: I know this from experience but I'll be damned if I can find a link to back it up (as opposed to just implying it, there must be an FAQ somewhere)

Comment: If I edit an **answer** does the author get notified?